# Como puedo añadir un índice a una clase en un arreglo con Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola quisiera ayuda en poder iterar un índice dentro de cada ${} para indexar las clases, estoy aprendiendo Vue 3 y es lo único que me falta, acá dejaré el código en cuestión.

```
<script>
export default{
    setup(){
        let servicios = [
            {title: 'OPERACIONES DE BUCEO', logo: ['fas', 'anchor'], class: `icon${}`},
            {title: 'REPARACIÓN DE EMBARCACIONES', logo: ['fas', 'screwdriver-wrench'], class: `icon${}`},
        ]
        return  {
            servicios
        }
    },
    methods:{
        Inum(){
            // this.servicios.forEach(item => {
            //     console.log(item.class);
            // })
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.Inum()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Lo quieres mostrar en el template?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) sobre el Array de servicios, por ejemplo:

```js
export default{
    setup(){
        const servicios = [
            {title: 'OPERACIONES DE BUCEO', logo: ['fas', 'anchor']},
            {title: 'REPARACIÓN DE EMBARCACIONES', logo: ['fas', 'screwdriver-wrench']},
        ]
        return  {
            servicios: servicios.map((servicio, index) => ({...servicio, class: `icon${index}`}));
        }
    },
    methods:{
        Inum(){
            // this.servicios.forEach(item => {
            //     console.log(item.class);
            // })
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.Inum()
    }
}
```

De esta forma se devuelve el mapeo del Array añadiendo el valor del índice dinámicamente.

Puedes ejecutar lo siguiente para que veas la salida:

```js
const servicios = [
  {title: 'OPERACIONES DE BUCEO', logo: ['fas', 'anchor']},
  {title: 'REPARACIÓN DE EMBARCACIONES', logo: ['fas', 'screwdriver-wrench']},
];

console.log(servicios.map((servicio, index) => ({...servicio, class: `icon${index}`})))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Usar chatGPT para responder está prohibido. Tu cuenta podría ser sancionada

Comment: ¿Y cómo aseguras que está usando chatGPT? :-)...

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo por aquí otra manera de hacerlo. Con un for in podrías obtener el mismo resultado.

```js
let servicios = [
    {title: 'OPERACIONES DE BUCEO', logo: ['fas', 'anchor'], class: 'icon'},
    {title: 'REPARACIÓN DE EMBARCACIONES', logo: ['fas', 'screwdriver-wrench'], class: 'icon'},
    {title: 'REPARACIÓN DE EMBARCACIONES', logo: ['fas', 'screwdriver-wrench'], class: 'icon'},
]

var i = 0;

for (let clave in servicios){
  var icon = servicios[clave].class;
  var contador = i++;
  console.log(icon+contador);
}
```